# How to calculate the costs of storing data in a contract?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

Lets say, I want to create a smart contract that can receive a record of data per hours, e.g. hourly rates of ETH/EUR. These data would be stored in an array.

What would each transaction cost me and how can I estimate these costs?

Answer (score 3):

By pushing a new element in the array, you are setting the storage value from zero to non-zero, therefore it has a cost of 20k gas, plus 5k to update the `length` member of the array, so it's a total of 25k gas.

So, if your function, say `function add_data(uint256[] data)` gets in parameter an array of length `n`, then your gas cost will have a lower bound of `25000*n`.

You can find more informations in the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf).

**Edit : integrated Jesse's comment.**

Comment: Pushing into a dynamic array will also incur 5000 gas cost to update the array length field.

Comment: Thank you! Will there be also a execution fee every time I call this method?

Comment: What do you mean? The execution fee is the gas you will pay.